# Calling function for minimum zoom in OpenLayers 3

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I'm developing a project in which OSM (OpenStreetMap) is default base map. There is one satellite image which is loaded after selecting it from layer list. I have assigned minzoom and maxzoom. Now I want when layer reach to minzoom that time satellite image will disappear and OSM layer appears as background layer. I have to call a function for this.

```
function zoomlevel()
    {
        if(maxZoom==18)
        {
            base_layer_definition_array.push(new ol.layer.Tile({
                  title: 'Satellite Image',
                group: "background",
                visible: false,
                crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
                source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                    urls:[
                        'http://localhost/tileserver/sate.png'
                    ],
                    minZoom: 0,
                    maxZoom: 21,
                    tilePixelRatio: 1
                })
            }));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any feedback ... ?

Answer (score 1):

You can watch to map view resolution changes and change the base layer, like:

```
map.getView().on('change:resolution', function(evt){
  var zoom = map.getView().getZoom();
  if (zoom < 18) {
    layer_satellite.setVisible(true);
  } else {
    layer_satellite.setVisible(false);
  }

  // or
  layer_satellite.setVisible(zoom < 18);
});
```